# Setting fields in Constructor vs.{ get;set;} properties

Tags: c#

Given a class:

```
public class NicePeople {
     public string VNP_Name;
     public int VNP_Age;
     public float VNP_Score;

     public NicePeople(string inName, int inAge, float inScore){
         VNP_Name = inName;
         VNP_Age = inAge;
         VNP_Score = inScore;
    }
}
```

and then you use it like:

```
NicePeople nicePerson = new NicePeople("Joe", 55, 1.6f);
```

Is there any difference between that and:

```
public class NicePeople {
     public string VNP_Name {set;get;}
     public int VNP_Age {set;get;}
     public float VNP_Score {set;get;}        
}
```

If not, are constructors just for when you want do some extra work (like checking for valid values etc.) and totally not needed for basic stuff?

Comment: Well aside from anything else, in your first case you have public *fields*, which is generally a bad idea IMO from the perspective of encapsulation and flexibility. (There's also the issue of the unconventional `VNP_` prefix before the fields and properties, and the `in` prefix for the parameters.) With a constructor, you could also potentially make the properties read-only...

Comment: Constructors are used to create _instances_ of a class. That's what your `nicePerson` object would be, an instance of the class. Properties are used to access the fields of a class from outside the class. So say, `nicePerson.VNP_Name = whatever`

Comment: Oh, I use those prefixes so it's pretty and I know what stuff means. Totally unnecessary, but the code is more readable **for me** that way.  However if you're saying it's not good practice, I won't use them.

Comment: I'm saying indeed that it's not good practice. I suggest you read up on the Microsoft naming conventions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions

Comment: @Matt L. I _think_ I understand what you mean, but I'm pretty sure I will need to buy a book. :)

Comment: @AdrianIftode If you thought I was questioning about Jon's comment up-votes, I better dare not to :). I was talking about question up-votes. Or perhaps I didn't understand you at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Real question here is when to use constructor parameters vs properties. Others have already mentioned reasons. Here's another one.

Use parameterized constructor when your class instance cannot be created without those values. Any optional attributes of the instance can be set using properties. Consider a `Person` class. Any person needs at least a name to be identified. Age can be optional information, however.

```
public class Person {
    public Person(string name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: YAY! NOW I understand what you smart people mean (still not sure what's the diff between parameters and properties, but I'll Google it). One more question - actually two: **1)** Someone said public FIELDS are bad?; **2)** So I use your class like: Person newGuy = new Person("Brad", 20);? And the I can do this: newGuy.Age = 25; **BUT NOT** newGuy.Name = "Bradley"; - right?

Comment: 1) > There's almost never a case where you need public fields. They are bad. Why? Google. It's simple to understand. 2) > Person won't allow age in ctor. Rest is right.

Answer (score 1):

**Fields VS. Properties**

**The first way** you are saying it is simply listing them as fields being accessed publicly without accessors:

```
 public string VNP_Name;
 public int VNP_Age;
 public float VNP_Score;
```

**The second way** is is wrapping a field with an accessor. It is called a property and is a member of a class not just a field. Such as this:

```
 public string VNP_Name {set;get;}
 public int VNP_Age {set;get;}
 public float VNP_Score {set;get;}
```

These act as normal get set statements would if they were broken apart. You could also do this which makes the properties set-able by the class only, but get-able publicly:

```
 public string VNP_Name { private set; get;}
 public int VNP_Age { private set; get;}
 public float VNP_Score { private set; get;}
```

**As Far as the Constructor is Concerned**
They are the same. You could easily set a field in a constructor just as you would a field.

Answer (score 0):

Erica,
  Indeed you can use constructors to validate your inputs for setting your class variables. Although, You can also have your setter methods do some validation itself on the inputs before updating the values of your class variables. There is one advantage of setting your values from the constructor over using a setter method and that is if you want immutability in your objects. This is a good consideration when you use concurrency in your program. Using constructor then is intended for basic and more advanced requirements in that case. So,if you want to make your objects immutable then, you can only use the constructor route to fill your final class variables. That means you create your instance with values from input provided with the constructor arguments and can never change them. It's good for concurrency, security, and integrity of your code. In the example below, I will be guaranteed that the SQLFile(queries contained here) and my DAOHelper(Database resources) will always be the same as what I started with during the startup of my application. There will be no setter methods here to update the values of my instance member sqlFile and daoHelper. Hope this helps.

```
private final SQLFile sqlFile;
private final DAOHelper daoHelper;

@Inject
public MapMetricsDAOImpl(@Named(SQLFILE_BEAN_NAME) final SQLFile sqlFile,
                         final DAOHelper daoHelper) throws SQLException {
    this.sqlFile = sqlFile;
    this.daoHelper = daoHelper;
}
```