# Constructor with one parameter but several fields inside? Why they use it? And when to use?

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

So let's say I am using this code. Your typical constructor has the same parameters as the fields within the square brackets, but this one doesn't --something more common than I expected btw.

```
    public class PetOwner
    {
        private readonly string OwnerName;
        private readonly List<PetAnimal> Pets;

        public PetOwner(string name)
        {
            OwnerName = name;
            Pets = new List<PetAnimal>();
        }
    }
```

Why shouldn't I create the constructor with both fields as the parameter which is the most typical thing and not only the owner's name?

Same here:

```
public class PetOwner
    {
        private readonly string OwnerName;

        public static int ownersCounter;

        public PetOwner(string name)
        {
            OwnerName = name;
            ownersCounter++;
        }
    }
```

Why and when to use?

Comment: who said it was the most typical thing?   I would strongly doubt that it is

Comment: This is a code design question that might get closed, so see [one discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359682/setting-fields-in-constructor-vs-getset-properties) that may help you

Comment: Let me give you a tip - if you accept an answer too early, people will not look into your question anymore and you might miss more interesting answers. Especially on the question like this, which can potentially cause a good discussion

Comment: okay, I left it open. There are quite a few interesting examples to show that behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example One**

In your first example the `OwnerName` is taken in as a argument, while `Pets` is intialized with a instance. This is required to actually use the field in any meaningfull way. And as a readonly, it has to happen here.

It would be entirely possible to also hand in the `Pet` collection with the constructor call. The designer choose not to, but setting/initalizing it from a existing collection or with a array initializer is not difficulty after creation.

My best guess why Collections are generally not assigned values in the Constructors, is the danger of Exceptions. The operation of filling or expanding Collections is very prone to OOM Exceptions. While the danger also exists with any `new` operation, it is orders of magnitude more likely with any actuall array write opereation.

**Example two**

In your second example the `OwnerName` is taken in as a argument, while a static variable `ownersCounter` is increased.

Sharing data via a static field is the most common beginners mistake with statics you can do. Outside of learning examples, you should avoid it like the plague. If the field was constant or readonly, the static nature would not mater. But this one is writeable.

What if you later need a programm with 2 different owner counts? (say vertebrates and invertebrates). Your class can not do that. It does not scale.

If somebody wants to have that kind of counting, it is generally **his** job to track it. This is a thing only code using your class can reliably do. It is the same reason that among all the Concurrent Collections, we do not have a Concurrent List. The index is by nature prone to race condition and the List class can do nothing to prevent it.

The user propably will also have a collection of PetOwner instances, so it would really only be a single call to `.Lenght` or `.Count` to get that number. Something that is so easily solved is not worth the hassle of tracking it internally.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering because I like questions like this. Because I like BS about code and laugh when people make stupid things in code

Here is what it is. Keyword here is "motivation". And I can see it here

```cs
public PetOwner(string name)
{
    OwnerName = name;
    Pets = new List<PetAnimal>();
}
```

The designer obviously wanted to make sure that pets list will be always there (`!= null`) and you can only add/remove them, and you can't have `PetOwner` without the name, hence, you must fully initialize it in constructor. That explains this particular design.

And, NO, this is not a "typical constructor" that "has the same parameters as the fields". Imagine class with 20 fields.. What you add to constructor is whatever needed to fully initialize your object. And if fields are many, just create a wrapper object and pass that to constructor.

Bottom line - your design. If you create classes for others (people) to consume, you basically think about how they are going to use it and you are trying to close all the holes that prevent them from doing something stupid. For example, here I would add

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

to close a hole of no-name owner.
So, there we go, my motivation is to simplify usage by other devs and their life easy, while also support good practice and design. Sometimes you leave objects open, that is - add parameter-less constructor. In this case it has potency of not being fully initialized but some frameworks like dependency injection may require such constructor, etc.

Comment: Many thanks for the replies, both T.S.'s and Christopher's posts answer my question. Is there a way to make both as accepted answers? I asked this 'cos I am into my second year of programming (gotta study a bit of everything, html, C# (my favourite language), java, css, php, javascript, xlts, xml, xpath, MySQL, Bootstrap, etc, and that puzzled me.